# What am I doing wrong in this induction question?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

***show by induction that, 
$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}=2-\frac{1}{2^n}$ for positive integers n.***

for the base case,
I am doing,
if $n=1$;
$LHS=\frac{1}{2^1}= \frac{1}{2}$

$RHS= 2- \frac{1}{2}= 2-\frac{1}{2}= \frac{3}{2}$

which is not the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $n=1$ the left hand is $1+\frac 12=\frac 32$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the sequence as the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{-i}$$

So with that:

If $n=0$: $\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{-i} = 2^{-0}=2^0=1$ .. which indeed equals $2-\frac{1}{2^0}=2-\frac{1}{1}=2-1=1$

(so, interestingly, the claim even holds for $04, and not just the positive integers)

For $n=1$ we get:

$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{-i} = 2^{-0}+2^{-1} = 1+\frac{1}{2}$ ... and that indeed equals what you found for the RHS.

Moral: Always try to state the claim that you are trying to prove as precisely as possible!